# Why are my styles not applying after a custom CSS file is included?

Tags: html, css, xml, magento2

I am using Magento 2.2.3. In my magneto theme added custom CSS file in the below path: `project/app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/css/custom.css`

I added source file in **default_head_blocks.XML** file.
after that added a page with following code in HTML content

```
<div class="freegotest"><span class="tested">count down custom code</span></div>
```

In **custom.css** code as

```
.tested { 
    color: red !important; 
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

By viewing the page source, I can see the custom CSS file included in the header, but the styles are not applying to the text.

Comment: Sounds like a browser cache problem.

Comment: cleared cache still it is not working.

Comment: Can you navigate to your `custom.css` stylesheet within the browser and confirm the css lines are actually there?

Comment: ya.navigated in browser written css is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML file must be named **default_head_blocks.xml** instead of **default_head_blocks.XML**.

Once the name changed, clear cache and static files :

1. Check if you are using dev mode With command line

```sh
php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

2. If developer mode is set to `production`, try to re-build static content

```sh
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

3. In any cases (production or developer), clear every cached files

```sh
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush;
```

Comment: Do you clear every cached files like mentionned in 3. also ?

Answer (score 0):

After updating from 2.1 to 2.3.2,  I find out that my custom CSS of swatches Magento_Swatches/web/css/swatches.css content from my custom theme did not merge to styles-m.css & styles-l.css. That caused layout issues in the product detail page.

I can’t find out how to make Magento 2.3.2 merge the custom CSS file to styles-m.css & styles-l.css

So I decide create a new .less file for Magento_Swatches. I created a new file Magento_Swatches/web/css/source/_module.less in my custom theme then move all content of

```
Magento_Swatches/web/css/swatches.css
```

to

```
Magento_Swatches/web/css/source/_module.less
```

then ran the command `setup:upgrade`

After that, the issue was resolved and all custom CSS was merged to styles-m.css & styles-l.css

Look likes Magento 2.3.2 does not allow you to use CSS directly in the module.